# BottomSheetDialogFragment collapsed when Recyclerview reached the upper border

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I use custom `BottomSheetDialogFragment` as the container for the Fragment that contains the `EditText` and `RecyclerView`.
The `RecyclerView` works fine until it reaches the upper border, at which point it doesn't stop (as it usually) but starts to close the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`
How do i fix this behavior?

[BottomSheetDialogFragment begins to collapse when the RecyclerView reaches the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxuS6.gif)

`layout_bottom_sheet.xml` as layout for BottomSheetDialogFragment

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
</androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>
```

`fragment_menu_search.xml` as layout for BottomSheetDialogFragment `@id/container`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!!skip unnecessary!!>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_bar_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_searched_dishes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        tools:itemCount="4"
        tools:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_menu_search_dish"
        tools:orientation="vertical" />

        <!-- fill space -->
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

I tried to override the ScrollListener of `RecyclerView` but it did not work